# Robocopy simultaneous copy after which other batch commands executed

Tags: batch-file, robocopy

```
del "%temp%\robocopy1.flag" "%temp%\robocopy2.flag" >nul
start /b cmd /c robocopy /s /mir D:\1 E:\1 ^& IF %ERRORLEVEL% lss 8 echo > "%temp%\robocopy1.flag" 
start /b cmd /c robocopy /s /mir D:\1 E:\2 ^& IF %ERRORLEVEL% lss 8 echo > "%temp%\robocopy2.flag" 
:wait
timeout 5
if not exist "%temp%\robocopy1.flag" goto wait
if not exist "%temp%\robocopy2.flag" goto wait
pause
echo success
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to do the copy processes simultaneously with source and destination of both copy processes being on same drive. As the storage drive has not multiple cores like the CPU, the data copying must be serialized for the drive. Running the two copying process simultaneously makes most likely the entire task slower than running each copy process separately one after the other, especially if the storage drive is a magnetic hard disk.

Comment: ^ very good point. It would only make sense if `\1` and `\2` folders were ntfs-junctions (or mount points) to different physical drives.

Comment: This can be circumvented though by [specifying bandwidth limit](https://yellowtriangle.wordpress.com/2012/06/28/bandwidth-throttling-with-robocopy/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `cmd /c` and `^&`  to combine the check with robocopy and use temporary files because variables won't be seen in the parent process:

```
del "%temp%\robocopy1.flag" "%temp%\robocopy2.flag" >nul
start /b cmd /c robocopy /s /mir F:\1 F:\dest\1 ^& IF %ERRORLEVEL% lss 8 echo ^>"%temp%\robocopy1.flag" 
start /b cmd /c robocopy /s /mir F:\1 F:\dest\2 ^& IF %ERRORLEVEL% lss 8 echo ^>"%temp%\robocopy2.flag" 

:wait
timeout 1 >nul
if not exist "%temp%\robocopy1.flag" goto wait
if not exist "%temp%\robocopy2.flag" goto wait

rem final robocopy
```

Note: `^` prevents immediate execution of `if` before robocopy and passes `&` to `cmd /c` so that the second command will be executed by the started command processor `cmd` after robocopy.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried out this snippet of code but its not going to the :Final loop. Its just looping inside the :CheckJob and :Wait.  I am not doing the same thing mentioned here. The thing I am developing is an application that will test validate some operations and i need to do some random/multiple read/write. Thanks in advance

Comment: That's because the variables are set in the child process, see the updated answer.

Comment: Sorry to be the bearer of bad news. But with this updated script the robocopy is not working. Gave a timeout syntax error but i fixed it, but now robocopy not happening. Thanks for the guidance and suggestion bro. Lemme see if I can fix this. Do let me know if u know something to fix this.

Comment: I made some changes and now the robocopy is working. But, the flag values are being set even before the copy is completed. I copied 1.13gb from source to two separate destination folders. And only 351mb have come in to two folders each in destination and the run ended. I gave pause to see the command output.

Comment: Updated the answer (forgot to escape output redirection and a space after timeout value).

Comment: Thank you! The code works after I made the change u posted. But can I know why that ^ is necessary?

Comment: Without `^` the line is parsed as (1) `start ......` and (2) `IF %ERRORLEVEL%.....` so the 2nd command is executed immediately after `start` finishes but since `start /b` finishes immeditely the 2nd command is executed next, not waiting for the sub-process to finish. The same goes for output redirection: without escaping the entire command line with `start` and `robocopy` is redirected to flag1 which is why previously the batch file didn't work correctly.

Comment: Thank you! You saved me from a great deal of headache! Much appreciated!